# Make 2 toolbar/footer buttons with 50% width with Swift/Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I'm trying to display a title bar, image, and then two buttons almost like below. The main differences are that I want to two item buttons to be 50% width and each a solid color (taking up the entire bottom of the screen). I'm not using a tab bar because the buttons are just to change the image out, not the entire view controller.

[image: screenshot]

So far using the storyboard, I'm just stuck on the buttons. I have them in a toolbar as bar button items. I then tried to set their width's in the controller:

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIBarButtonItem!
@IBOutlet weak var secondButton: UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.firstButton.width = self.view.bounds.width / 2
    self.secondButton.width = self.view.bounds.width / 2
}
```

[image: screenshot]

I believe they're being set properly, but the toolbar is forcing some space to be in front of the first button. I haven't even made it to changing their background colors yet, but I'm hoping that will be simple once I finish the spacing.

I'm pretty new to iOS development, so any tips are appreciated. I'm aiming for having it work universally but I'd settle for getting it working on iPhone locked portrait.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previous answers didn't solve the problem, it looks like there's some internal padding with using a toolbar. That and you might not be able to add constraints to Bar Buttons.

My actual solution is:

Remove Bar Buttons and Toolbar. Add two UIButtons to the bottom. Add the following constraints

First Button

- Leading Space to Superview

Second Button

- Leading Space to Superview

First Botton and Second Button

- Bottom Space to Superview
- Proportional Width to ImageView with a 0.5 multiplier

Answer (score 7):

Using Autolayout is relative easy, You need to set the width of the button equals to the SuperView and set the Multiplier constant to 0.5

Or set the Toolbar width equals to Superview with Multiplier 1.0 and then the UIButtons equals the toolbar's width but with Multiplier 0.5

Something like this

[image]

Comment: Some reason I'm unable to pin the buttons and the toolbar was already set to be pinned to superview with leading and trailing space.

Comment: Maybe is the best way yo accomplish your goal to remove the toolbar and put an UIView there with equals width the superview and then insert two buttons with equal width to the UIView and Multiplier 0.5

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing

Answer (score 1):

If you're using auto layout, you need to set your toolbar's width equal to the container view with a width constraints. Then set width of two items equal to each other, set those spacings to zero.

There's no need to set their width manually.

BTW, do not forget to do the same thing to your UIImageView if you want it to be full width.

**Helpful links:**

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1
http://www.raywenderlich.com/64392/video-tutorial-beginning-auto-layout

Comment: Some reason I'm unable to pin the buttons and the toolbar was already set to be pinned to superview with leading and trailing space. The space at the beginning seems independent of that

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** using **Storyboard**:

You can add `Flexible Space Bar Button Item` to your Toolbar, which will allow equal spacing of your icons. Place them in between your Bar Button Items, and they will automatically fill out the space in your Toolbar.

See below:

[image: Storyboard Flexible Space Bar Button Item]